# How to resize an array of int larger and have the default values null and not 0

Tags: c#, arrays

From my understanding arrays are always nullable. However when I want to resize an array to a larger size I would expect it to return nulls in the new elements. However it returns 0;

Example:

```
int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 3 };
Array.Resize(ref myArray, 100);
int? shouldBeNull = myArray[3];
```

How do I get the myArray[3] to return null and not 0 like it is currently?

Comment: Its because default `int` is `0`.

Comment: int is not nullable, `int?` is

Comment: Array is nullable, int is not.

Comment: I read that arrays are always nullable and assumed that meant their elements. Solution was to declare int?[] myArray = { 1, 2, 3 };

Comment: Stackoverflow is a funny old place, where people get downvoted for asking questions that they don't know the answer to...

Comment: @MatthewWatson I downvoted your comment because you forgot to capitalize the "O" in "StackOverflow".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From my understanding arrays are always nullable

They are, in the sense that `int[] someArray = null` compiles.

An array of a non-nullable type still can't contain `null` values though. It will contain `default(T)`, which is `0` in the case of `int`.

It seems you're looking for an array of nullable ints, or `int?[]`.